# I need help understanding looping through two dimensional (2D) arrays

Tags: c#

I am trying my best to understand 2D arrays in term of the value been printed out I used to nested for loop to print out my value but instead of print out row and column I went for printing out [column , column] intentionally just to see what values will be returned. i dont want fixing the code as answer i want explanation for someone

Can someone explain me why am I getting the result of 159 printed. I understand on the first loop the compiler get the first value in the first row of the column but on the next loop iteration why does it print out 5 instead of of 4?

I get the first loop purpose which is row for every 1 loop for row execute the column loop 3 times.

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] _tacToe = new int[3, 3]
            {
              {1,2,3} ,
              {4,5,6},
              {7,8,9}
            };
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("gggg");
                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                {
                    Console.Write(_tacToe[column, column]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Result:

```
gggg
159
gggg
159
gggg
159
```

Comment: _tacToe[row, columm], instead of column,column ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `column` as both indices you are incrementing the row and column index simultaneously

```
for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
{
    Console.Write(_tacToe[column, column]);
}

/*
column = 0 _tacToe[0, 0] -> prints 1
column = 1 _tacToe[1, 1] -> prints 5
column = 2 _tacToe[2, 2] -> prints 9
*/
```

Comment: than you.  you explained it well

Answer (score 1):

OK so it appears you already know the code is printing `_tacToe[column, column]` (sic) and you want an explanation of why your array of:

```
{ 1, 2, 3 },
{ 4, 5, 6 },
{ 7, 8, 9 }
```

prints `159` on each iteration of the outer loop.

You can find the reason why by simply stepping through the loop with a debugger. On the first iteration of the "row" loop, you have a row value of 0. Then the inner "column" loop will loop through the values 0, 1, 2. On each of these values you are getting the `_tacToe[column, column]` value (deliberately, as you say). This means you are getting:

```
_tacToe[0, 0]
_tacToe[1, 1]
_tacToe[2, 2]
```

Which you can imagine as a diagonal line through the data:

{ **1**, 2, 3 },

{ 4, **5**, 6 },

{ 7, 8, **9** }

Then we have the next "row" iteration of 1. Since only the column value is used, this is again:

```
_tacToe[0, 0]
_tacToe[1, 1]
_tacToe[2, 2]
```

And so on.

Which is why you get 159 each iteration.

Answer (score -1):

You mixed up your rows and columns.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {

    int[,] _tacToe = new int[3, 3] {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {

        for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
            Console.Write(_tacToe[row, column]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I went ahead and fixed that for you, and made your code more legible*.

** My more legible may very well differ from yours!

**EDIT:**

The reason the output is 159, 159, 159 is because you completely ignored your `row` variable.
While the code wasn't the most detailled explanation, it answered your question fully. You mixed up your rows and columns.
By ignoring the value from the first loop, you only ever executed the second loop with the same value.

Your code was looping through the array using the exact same values each time. 
By swapping the first `column` with `row` the code then didn't ignore the value from the first loop.

Comment: Hello thank for answering but am not looking for a  fix i want could you read my question well please